# Laravel Migration - down() not working in multiple database connections - Table already exists error

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

In my lravel project I tried to create table in multiple mysql databases except mainDB. Table created successfully in all dbs, but in migrate:fresh command i got Table already exists error.

```
 public function down()
    {
        $connections = Config::get('database.connections');
        foreach($connections as $conn){
            if($conn['database'] !== 'mainDB' && !is_array($conn['database'])){
                Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $conn);
                Schema::connection($conn['database'])->getConnection()->reconnect();
                Schema::connection($conn['database'])->dropIfExists('user_details');
                DB::purge($conn['database']);
                DB::disconnect($conn['database']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `migrate:refresh`„ this will delete all tables and create new

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Hope this will help you and run your migration smoothly.

Thanks.

Comment: Most Welcome!! It will be great if you can accept answer.